Trying to figure out this movie about this mansion/castle killing people
So all I remember about the movie is that this guy, who probably owns the mansion/castle but the movie isn't clear, invites a bunch of people to stay at his place for something (I can't remember why he invited them) and his castle thing starts moving around its walls and such and killing people and the host pisses of the house so the house kills him too and no one can get out. 2 people end up surviving. There are moving suits of armor and I somewhat remember a lion or tiger or something to that effect. Does anyone know what movie this is? It was made at least 2005 or earlier, but not later than that.

Is there a scene where something in fireplace knocks someone's head off?

The film you are looking for sounds like House on Haunted Hill from 1999.  The film is actually a remake from the 1959 Vincent Price classic.

Evelyn gives Price a lengthy guest list; he shreds it to spite her and then creates one of his own. Five guests arrive for the party -
  Jennifer Jenzen (aka Sara Wolfe) (Ali Larter), Eddie Baker (Taye
  Diggs), Melissa Margaret Marr (Bridgette Wilson), Dr. Donald Blackburn
  (Peter Gallagher), and Pritchett himself. The guests are not the ones
  Price invited—neither Evelyn nor Price know who they are. Despite
  this, Price continues the party's theme, offering $1 million to each
  guest who stays in the house and survives until morning, with any
  person not making it having his money added to the pot.

The film includes a scene with the walls closing in on the guests.

The security gates are tripped, locking everyone inside.
  After finding some hand guns, Sara, Eddie and Pritchett decide to take one of the
  guns. Meanwhile, Price scolds Carl Schecter (Max Perlich), a company
  employee - who has developed a series of harmless traps to scare the
  guests— for not letting him know he planned to pull a stunt like
  closing the iron gates. When Schecter states that he is not
  responsible, Price believes Evelyn is responsible. Meanwhile,
  Pritchett, Eddie and Sara go into the lower levels to find a way to
  open the gates.

